# How to change an english LaTeX template to accept greek main text?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, templates, polyglossia, greek

New to LaTeX here. My goal is to write a thesis in greek. If possible, I would prefer an answer which uses `polyglossia` package instead of `babel`. I have made a simple test document using the former which works fine:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\title{Υπόστεγο απορριμάτων αερολιμένα Σάμου, Τεχνικές παρατηρήσεις}
\author{Κωνσταντίνος}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
...
<some greek text>
...
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to do the same thing but using an [english template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) which is more complex and has a `main.tex` as well as a `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` file. The fact is that by naively copying the same commands and adding them to the main.tex file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.5 (27/8/17)
%
% This template was downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
...
```

I get a ton of errors, which is expected. Most of them are:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Greek 
script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \greekfont with \newfontfamily.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 {\small\verb
               !\hypersetup{urlcolor=red}!}, or
```

or

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ifnum \c@chapter <\@ne \space \gr@ill@value 
                                             {\c@chapter }\else \ifnum \c@chapt
l.8 ...I change the colors of links?}{3}{section.16}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The question is how do you even implement this? I mean, should I make changes in the .cls file as well? or only in the main.tex file? Do I miss something trivial here?

Comment: Your version of Arial does not support Greek. You could try "Linux Libertine O" as before, or you could try "Palatino Linotype" if you have it, ...

Comment: I have tried with "Linux libertine" as well, still doesn't work. In fact when I use "Arial" with my simple test document, it works fine, so I don't think it's the font not supporting greek. I edit it so it won't confuse others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MastersDoctoralThesis` class you are using makes use of `babel`. It might be possible to get rid of this, but this seems to be more complicated than necessary. However, the only way I know to use `babel-greek` together with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is to load `fontspec` *before* `babel`. Since `babel` is loaded by the class, we have to do this *before* `\documentclass` I made the following changes to `main.tex` from the mentioned template:

- put `\RequirePackage{fontspec}` *before* `\documentclass`
- replace `english` with `greek` in the class options
- replace loading of `inputenc`, `fontenc` and `mathpazo` packages with

  ```
  \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
  \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  ```
- Replace `\thesistitle` and `\author` with the text from your example

Result:

[image]

Obviously, you will have to replace more of the boilerplate text.

Here the complete preamble:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
greek, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}


\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Υπόστεγο απορριμάτων αερολιμένα Σάμου, Τεχνικές παρατηρήσεις} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{Κωνσταντίνος} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{http://www.university.com}{University Name}} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{\href{http://department.university.com}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{http://researchgroup.university.com}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{http://faculty.university.com}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: could you paste the final code, because it doesn't seem to work. I might be missing something.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΑτζαράκης see the update

Comment: Thanks @Ralf Stubner, this seems to be working fine. In the `.cls` , at the requirements declaration, he uses `\RequirePackage{babel}`. Could something similar be done with `polyglossia`?

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΑτζαράκης That might be possible, but I have not tried it. Any particular reason why you prefer `polyglossia` over `babel` for Greek?

Comment: I thought that `babel` required  a command `\textenglish` or sth like that every time you want to revert back to english, but seems I was wrong. So I wanted `polyglossia` just for convenience.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΑτζαράκης `babel` used to use an input method based on Latin characters that required such font switching commands. Nowadays you can use UTF-8 input. However, both `babel` and `polyglossia` use such language switching commands to change the hyphenation patterns or the used font etc. As long as these things are not important in your application, you can get by without these language switching commands.

Comment: thank you!  you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\newenvironment{greek}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
To~u d`e poso~u t`o m'en >esti diwrism'enon, t`o d`e suneqes.

This is for test
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]